# ouc process running at 98% CPU

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

When I open a few different applications, the temperature quickly surpasses 200 F, however, when I'm working lightly, it is around 170 F.  It just seems like ever since I upgraded to Mavericks, it's heating up very often and fans go crazy, which is by design I guess.

I just don't know what this ouc process is and why it's using so much CPU.  I force quit it, but it comes back in a few minutes again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given `ouc` is not a process that ships with Mac OS X it appears a third party product is causing the problem.

Searching the web suggests `ouc` is embedded within an application called "Mobile Partner.app".

If you have this application, please report the problem to the developers.

### Manual Removal

It is always better to use the removal process provided by the developer; however, if Mobile Partner does not provide a removal tool, you might like to disable the `ouc` process manually.

You mention force quitting results in an immediate relaunching. This suggests the `ouc` process is managed by a launchd job ticket. launchd is a watchdog process that will monitor processes and relaunch any that run into trouble - such as crashing or being force quit.

Take a look in the following folders for a launchd job ticket associated with `ouc`:

- ~/Library/LaunchAgents
- ~/Library/LaunchDaemons
- /Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchDaemons

The files in these folders are text files and can be read using TextEdit or a dedicated text editing tool, such as [TextWrangler](http://barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

If you find a file mentioning `ouc`, move it out of the parent folder and restart.

As @oma mentions, if you can not find a launchd job ticket, look inside `/Library/StartupItems` for a folder or file containing `ouc`. Delete the `ouc` folder and restart.

Comment: Cool thanks.  It was indeed an app that I installed recently when I used wireless internet overseas.  It was used in conjunction with the USB internet stick made by Huawei and service provided by mtel ISP.

Comment: i had the runouc issue where 97% CPU was used for this process, on the activity monitor i just selected the process and hit quit,
my battery life became normal and the service sign on the battery went off

Comment: I also have a Huawei USB modem and this same overheating issue with runouc running on the activity monitor. I forced it to quit and everything went back to normal.

Comment: I am also having the same problem and am also using a Huawei USB modem. I have forced the item to quit, but it still starts up again from time to time. I have now manually removed the file as directed above. Seems to be much better. Thanks for the tips

Comment: this didn't cut it for me. after long time (weeks) of this reoccuring, I found it here: `/Library/StartupItems`. Delete subfolder `StartOuc`. There are HW folders there too that I deleted. I'm staying away from Huawei from now on.